# Is there a way to open a sql file in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have thousands of stored procedures in my data base. And I can't stand scrolling through the entire list to find the SPROC I'm looking for. Is there a command in sql server mgmt studio to open the file in the editor like 'OPEN dbo.SomeStoredProcedureName'

Comment: Have look at [Redgate SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/). I think it would be helpful for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no T-SQL command to do this, as SSMS is just a client management tool. Your best bet is to use the Filter tool built in to SSMS:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is such command but if you just want to see and not update you could use

```
sp_helptext 'dbo.SomeStoredProcedureName'
```

This messes up the formatting so you shouldn't use it to update (while you can). I also map a key to it Ctrl-F1 that can be used to just write the name and select an d press Ctrl-F1.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've got lots of options, depending on exactly what you're trying to do:

- You can "open file" and graphically browse to the directory you want, then graphically scroll down to and open the file you want.
- You can "use" the database you want, and "exec" the stored procedure you want from a command-line query window.
- You can "exec sp_helptext XXX" the stored procedure to see the text in a command-line query window.
- You can use "filter" in the GUI to eliminate stuff you *don't* want to see
- You can write a VBScript or Powershell script to do the same stuff the SSMS GUI lets you do.
- Etc etc

Answer (score 0):

You could export the whole database to a creation script.  Then it would be easy to search in your favorite file viewer.

From Management Studio you can right-click on the database, choose Tasks->Generate Scripts, and then select "Stored procedures". If you're just browsing, this is very handy.  Also good to store such scripts in your code repository.

Answer (score 0):

[SqlSmash](http://www.sqlsmash.com/) lets you navigate easily to any object (including stored procedures) in SSMS.

[image]

[Source](http://www.sqlsmash.com/blog/2014/06/22/navigate-to-any-object-in-object-explorer/)

Disclaimer: I am the developer for the addin.